# Como retirar a barra de título do app android VisualStudio C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, app, visual-studio-2017

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com dificuldade para retirar a barra de titulo do app que estou desenvolvendo, ja tentei pelo android studio e falhei miseravelmente assim como no visual studio, como não sou bom em java optei pelo visual que tenho mais afinidade. Como posso resolver esse problema ??

Comment: Testou a sugestão apresentada em minha resposta?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a resposta dada à mesma pergunta no SO EN

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480724/xamarin-remove-app-title